# Best way to import csv with "1232,12" as number

Tags: r, csv, import

I want to import a csv that has this configuration

```
c1,c2,c3
1,"32,12",A
2,"23,43",B
```

I am trying to import it using either fread (from library data.table) or read.table, but c2 is always impoted as a character column. I know I can convert it to number, but what I am expecting is to import it directly as a numeric data.colum

What I have tried is:

```
data<-fread("/home/mydata.csv",quote="")
data<-fread("/home/mydata.csv",quote="\"")
data<-fread("/home/mydata.csv",dec=",",quote="\"")
```

But both does not work as I want to do

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `read.csv2`. Apparently it read your data at the first try.

```
dat <- read.csv2(text = '
c1,c2,c3
1,"32,12",A
2,"23,43",B
', sep = ",", quote = '"')

dat
  c1    c2 c3
1  1 32.12  A
2  2 23.43  B
```

P.S. `data` already is the name of a base R function, it's better to use something else.